# If it carries out, how can an iPhone terminal be locked using MDM?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am using "APNs" of Apple, and "MDM". 
The list of applications is also acquirable from the iOS terminal using "MDM". 
But, only the lock of a device cannot be performed. 
An error message is not displayed. 
The payload of a success.   PUT is carried out to the server. 
However, an iPhone terminal can be used ordinarily, without being locked. 
"DeviceLock" of MDM Protocol Reference is being used for the payload. 
If it carries out, how can an iPhone terminal be locked using MDM? 
Please let me know. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check device logs when you are sending "DeviceLock" command.

When you are sending "DeviceLock" command from MDM server then what is the change in iPhone screen?
For me iPhone screen is locked when "DeviceLock" command is sent and I can again swipe the finger to unlock the device.

Comment: Can the device be locked with a passcode using MDM? (i.e. the passcode is not set, and I enforce the user to enter my passcode to use the device)