# Lock iPhone device with a passcode

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am currently using APNS MDM API, I want to lock the device with a given PASSCODE. I have succeeded in locking the device but I want that if the passcode is not set, then I want to be able to choose the password to lock the device.

How can I do this? Is it possible by using the MDM API?

Comment: @tony blue how did you lock the device?

Comment: iOsBoy please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665966/if-it-carries-out-how-can-an-iphone-terminal-be-locked-using-mdm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this using MDM.